# How to access local variable from Dojo declarative widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a declarative Dijit calendar inside a custom widget, and I want to access a non-global variable from within `data-dojo-props` rather than needing to reference a global variable.

**myWidgetTemplate.html:**

```
<div class="${baseClass}" data-dojo-attach-point="wrapperNode">

    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Calendar" 
        data-dojo-attach-point="calWidget" 
        id="myCalendar" 
        data-dojo-props="isDisabledDate: myIsDisabledDate"></div>

</div>
```

I can't access `myIsDisabledDate` unless it's in the global scope, which is...less than desirable. I can place my local method in my containing widget, and insert it by using a template field:

```
data-dojo-props="isDisabledDate: ${myIsDisabledDate}"
```

But this only works because I happen to be working in a widget template here. Is it possible to reference a variable/function that's in another module from a declarative widget in the page? I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
data-dojo-props="isDisabledDate: uiModule.myIsDisabledDate"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only scope a declarative widget can access is the global scope, since it lives on the global scope (the DOM). All other modules that you need are usually inside a `require()` block, which has its own scope.

So, the only way to access a property from another module inside a declarative widget, is by adding that module to the global scope.

### Programmatically

For example:

```
define("uiModule", {
    title: "Some title"    
});

require(["uiModule", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/parser"], function(uiModule) {
    window.uiModule = uiModule;   
});
```

And then you can do:

```html
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"
  data-dojo-props="label: uiModule.title"></button>
```

### Declarative

Or you could make it even shorter by using the declarative markup:

```html
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"
    data-dojo-props="label: uiModule.title">

    <script type="dojo/require">
        uiModule: "uiModule"
    </script>
</button>
```

This still means that the `uiModule` is still added to global scope though. However, if you create a declarative widget, then that instance is always available on global scope, for example, if you create a button with ID `btn`, then you can access it by using `window.btn`. You could use that feature to add the `uiModule` to the button itself, for example:

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"
    data-dojo-props="label: btn.uiModule.title" id="btn">

    <script type="dojo/require">
      "btn.uiModule": "uiModule"
    </script>
```

I combined the three examples into a fiddle that demonstrates them all: http://jsfiddle.net/cey4e/